# How install python interpreter on an android device

Tags: applications, python

I cant download the  http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/ because in my country is block this URL. Where can I install the python app for android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [QPython - Python for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hipipal.qpyplus). This appears to be an IDE and Python script runner for Android.

Comment: I use a android tablet in cuba, i cant download the app from my device I need a link direct from my computer